# Variable not found

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a grid on a form populated by a view. I added a button to filter the data.

```
cFilter = UPPER(ALLTRIM(INPUTBOX("Filter sur :","Spectech France - Suivi DDP")))

SELECT vwDdp_all

LOCATE FOR ALLTRIM(ref_client) = cFilter
IF FOUND()
    SET FILTER TO ref_client = cFilter 
    THISFORM.grdDDP.Column10.SetFocus
ENDIF
```

I get a "Variable cFilter not found" error.  What I don't understand is that the error comes after the above code has already run; and in the debugger, the guilty method is indicated as "MyForm.grdDDP". Nothing else. How can I find where it's actually looking for this variable?

Comment: Using an error handling program shows that the error occured in MyForm.grdDDP.Error (??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable cFilter would have to be a global for your code to work.

If you don't want to use a global variable, you can do something like this.

```
cFilter = UPPER(ALLTRIM(INPUTBOX("Filter sur :","Spectech France - Suivi DDP")))

SELECT vwDdp_all

LOCATE FOR ALLTRIM(ref_client) = cFilter
IF FOUND()
   lcFiltClause = [ref_client = ']+cFilter+[']
   SET FILTER TO &lcFiltClause
   THISFORM.grdDDP.Column10.SetFocus
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1):

A filter expression must be visible at all times you navigate in the bound cursor. You could do:

```
Local lcFilter
lcFilter = Textmerge('ref_client = "<< m.cFilter >>"')
Set Filter To &lcFilter
```

BUT, set filter is one of the commands that almost all the developers have it on their "not to use" list. Especially with a grid, you shouldn't use "set filter". Instead you could simply use a query as the grid's source. Or if that ref_client is an indexed field then you could use "Set range" instead (it doesn't need a global variable or any & trick).

Comment: The filter was a user requirement (they want to imitate the HUGE  Excel worksheet the app is supposed to replace) but I will take your advice and try using "Set Range".

Comment: Yes, set filter doesn't work well with grids (observe the misleading scrollbar).

Comment: BTW, you may want to utilize (now free and released to public) Foxyclasses grids instead, particularly the LocatorGrid class.